# (Python) 'NoneType' object is not callable (Linked List implementation)

Tags: python, callable

So i solved a couple of problems already, by getting help here, and
from people i know. the root of my problems is that i don't know how to wrap None so
that i don't keep getting these errors of not having the attribute, or not callable.

For this linked list, all i really need is insert and printlist.
I didn't include print list because it is simple, and is not causing problems.

The error is under Linked_List, under insert,  under the elif.
It's commented so:  #<----ERROR

Here is the code:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, word):
    self.data = word
    self.next = None
def nextNode(self):
    if self.next is not None:
        return self.next
    else:
        return None
def getData(self):
    return self.data
def setNext(self, node):
    self.next = node
def hasNext(self):
    if self.next == None:
        return False
    else:
        return True


class Linked_List:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = Node(None)
    self.isempty = True
def insert(self, word):
    newNode = Node(word)
    prev = self.head.nextNode()
    current = self.head.nextNode()
    nextFound = False #the next would be the current when it is less than node
    #Look for position to insert:

    #When empty
    if self.isempty == True:
        self.isempty = False
        self.head = newNode
    #When has more than one
    elif self.head.hasNext():
        while nextFound == False:
            if current.getData() > newNode.getData():
                prev = current
                current = curent.nextNode()
            else:
                nextFound = True
        #Insert
        prev.next().setNext(newNode) # <-------ERROR -----HERE~~
        newNode.setNext(current)
    else:
        #When only has one node not empty
        if self.head.getData() > newNode.getData():
            self.head.setNext(newNode)
        else:
            newNode.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = newNode
```

Insertion:

```
lList.insert(string)
```

---

Solved Here:

```
class Linked_List:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = Node(None)
    self.isempty = True
def insert(self, word):
    newNode = Node(word)
    prev = self.head.nextNode()
    current = self.head.nextNode()
    nextFound = False #the next would be the current when it is less than node
    #Look for position to insert:

    #When empty
    if self.isempty == True:
        self.isempty = False
        self.head = newNode
    #When has more than one
    elif self.head.hasNext():
        while nextFound == False and current != None:
            if current.getData() > newNode.getData():
                prev = current
                if current.hasNext():
                    current = current.nextNode()
                else:
                    current = None
            else:
                nextFound = True
        #Insert
        prev.setNext(newNode)
        newNode.setNext(current)
    else:
        #When only has one node not empty
        if self.head.getData() > newNode.getData():
            self.head.setNext(newNode)
        else:
            newNode.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = newNode
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your patience. (sarcasm)
I solved my own question by asking someone else, and i went ahead and posted it. Of course i had another problem. Which i was going to attempt my self. That is why i left the question as is. Plus i didn't know i could edit the whole post and make another question. Sad for me, now i get all these minuses for trying my best.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I've withdrawn my downvote. However, you still didn't post *all of the relevant code*. Why do you keep expecting that everyone wants to waste their time on guessing what have you written?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by relevant code.
The only other thing i have on the linked list is a print method. for my intentions, i only need to insert and print.

Comment: If you have error in the `insert` method, then somehow you call it, right? I can't see any calls to this method in the code you've posted. So something is missing...
Also, please try my answer... It still looks like you put a non-Node object into `head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you use it? I'm guessing that you do something like `yourList.insert(1)`. In your code you do: `self.head = node`, where `node` is what user have passed to `insert`. So, on the next call to `insert` you end up trying to call an `int` or anything you've tried to put into the list. You need to wrap any objects given by the user with your `Node` class:

```
def insert(self, thing):
    node = Node(thing)
    //...
```

However, please remember to post all of the relevant code, so the people trying to help you won't have to guess.

EDIT: still, after the edit the case remains the same. You don't wrap objects passed to your list, so you keep trying to call `Node` methods on non-Node objects...

Comment: the head will always be empty on this one. the node inserted would be after the head.

Comment: You are right. that is what i am struggling with. These constant bugs of mine are the effect of that cause. I don't know how to wrap.

Comment: The way you do it now seems OK. What's the error message now? What's `item`?

Comment: item is just a string, like 'asdgfasdgasd'.
The error message is in the main post's heading, and the line is inside Insert, it's elif and has a comment saying #ERROR <-----